# How to Unlock Maxtor Blackarmor Portable hard drive disk

Tags: hard-drive, unlock

I have a Maxtor portable Hard drive Disk.  I can't unlock it. It has a launcher.exe file . Is there any unlock utility ?

Comment: the portable hard drive disk is locked with password. It needs to be unlocked to access the files inside. It shows 34 Mb but if it unlocks it is 320GB. I know the password for the drive . there is no utility to open the unlock manager.

Answer (score -1):

plug the hard drive in a usb port.  then click on open to view files.  a window will open and you will see the word  launcher click on the icon and that will take you to the unlock screen where you will type in your password. then click on unlock at the lower corner of the screen

Comment: The launcher is a `.exe` file built for windows, so I'm not sure your solution here will work.